# realm custom Database insert Data alert Permission denied

Tags: realm

When using Realm custom database insert data prompt

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'XX: Permission denied'

but the data has been inserted.

My code:

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm realmWithURL:[self dataBasePath:kRealmCustomDBName]];
realm.configuration.readOnly = NO;
NSLog(@"path = %@",realm.configuration.fileURL);
WEAKSELF
[realm transactionWithBlock:^{
    NSDictionary *dic = @{
                          kRealmPrimaryKey:[weakSelf ret64bitString],
                          kRealmAvatarData:hiSchool.avatar,
                          kRealmTitle:hiSchool.title,
                          kRealmSubtitle:hiSchool.subTitle,
                          kRealmAge:hiSchool.age,
                          kRealmDate:hiSchool.date,
                          kRealmMale:hiSchool.isMale,
                          kRealmWeight:hiSchool.weight,
                          kRealmHeight:hiSchool.height
                          };
    [HiSchool createInRealm:realm withValue:dic];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, (In case this might be causing the issue) it's not really good practice to change the properties of a `RLMRealmConfiguration` object that's already been assigned to an `RLMRealm` instance. In this case, all of the configuration was performed inside `[RLMRealm realmWithURL:]` so modifying it after the fact could lead to some instability. In any case, unless `readOnly` was set to YES before you set it in your code, that shouldn't be causing any issues here.

The only other thing I can think of is that your `fileURL` might be malformed. There was a [Realm Java instance where a similar error message occurred](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1813) because of an illegal character in the file path.

I'd recommend cleaning up your `RLMRealm` instance creation. Create a new `RLMRealmConfiguration` instance, set its `fileURL` (and if it's necessary), its `readOnly` properties in there, and then create the `RLMRealm` instance using `[RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:error:]`. Also, make sure your `fileURL` value is a proper file URL (i.e., created with `[NSURL fileURLWithString:]`.) and is pointing to a directory in which your app has write-access.

Good luck!